# Pick columns from csv (FMX, C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I am reading one column of data out of a big CSV file (column 3).  I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.  Right now i read each entire row, and then pick out my column.

```
String S;
TStringList *List = new TStringList;
List->LoadFromFile(myCSV); // load the CSV file
std::auto_ptr<TStringList>pListA(new TStringList);
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {   // for testing just getting first 400 rows.  
pListA->Text = StringReplace(List[0].Strings[i], ",", "\r\n", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll); 
S = pListA->Strings[3];  
// do something with this value from column 3
}
```

This code works fine, but it has to read the entire row of CSV data just to let me get that one column. Below is sample of the first 2 rows from the CSV data:

`1,0,-6856,12830,8458,-16666,98717,-10718,-80874,49999,-99998,98569,99998,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

`2,8948,-6856,12830,8458,-16666,39641,63125,-99973,99998,-99998,39385,99998,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

**UPDATE**: Based on Remy's code I ended up with this below.

```
    TStreamReader* Reader;
    Reader = new TStreamReader(myCSV);
    while (!Reader->EndOfStream)
     {
     String S = Reader->ReadLine();
     int start = PosEx(_D(","), S, 1);
     start = PosEx(_D(","), S, start+1) + 1;
     int end = PosEx(_D(","), S, start);
     S = S.SubString1(start, end-start);
             // use S 
     }
    Reader->Close();
    delete Reader->BaseStream;
    delete Reader;
```

Comment: You don't need to `Close()` the Reader just before `delete`'ing it. And you don't need to `delete` its `BaseStream`, the Reader's destructor will handle that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `TStringList` at all, you could use `TStreamReader` to read each line, and simply parse each line using `Strutils::PosEx()` and `String::SubString1()` to extract just the 3rd column value.

```cpp
// NOTE: in C++11 and later, use std::unique_ptr instead!
std::auto_ptr<TStreamReader> Reader(new TStreamReader(myCSV)); // load the CSV file
while (!Reader->EndOfStream)
{
    String S = Reader->ReadLine();
    int start = PosEx(_D(","), S, 1);
    start = PosEx(_D(","), S, start+1) + 1;
    int end = PosEx(_D(","), S, start);
    S = S.SubString1(start, end-start);
    // do something with this value from column 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy!  The `std::auto_ptr` line caused an error --> `[bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(753): E2285 Could not find a match for 'std::auto_ptr<TStringReader>::auto_ptr(TStreamReader *)'`.  I tried with `unique_ptr` as well but same problem.  See the UPDATE in my question, I found [this link](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.14/codeexamples/en/StreamCharRdWr_(C%2B%2B)) and made few changes.  I don't know why it had problem with the auto_ptr.

Comment: @relayman357 should be `TStreamReader` instead of `TStringReader`